# Why is the advanced search not working with price criteria in magento?

Tags: search, magento

The advanced search with all the default product attributes are working fine and gives the desired result except for the price criteria where even if i fill the values with the correct range and price that is present in the product list, the message "No items were found using the following search criteria" is displayed.I tried printing the query that is in the model class within function getProductCollection(), and it seemed ok.Also in the query I checked if all the required attributes are selected and that also seemed fine..Can someone please give me some suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it fixes this, but a lot of similar things are fixed by going to system -> cache management

and then running

"rebuild layered navigation indexes"

and

"rebuild search index"

Whilst you are there ... if you have flat catalog enabled, that could also cause a problem, so you should rebuild that as well!

Comment: Whenever  I search price from 0 to 999 no search result is displayed for my development server, But when I do same search on my local server search results are fine.Please suggest some solution.Reindexing and cache clearing is not working for me.